# Solve $y''' + 4y'' + 5y' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, wronskian

Find the solution to the $y''' + 4y'' + 5y' = 0$ using the wronskian.

What I have done:

$$y^3+4y^2+5y=0 \\
\implies y(y^2+4y+5) \\
\implies y^2(y+4)+5y=0 \\
\implies y+4 = -\frac{5}{y} \\
\implies \cdots \\ y = i-2$$

The solution is $$y = e^{-2x}(A\cos(x)+B\sin(x))$$

Using the wronskin for $1, e^{-2x}\cos(x), e^{-2x}\sin(x)$, I get the solution $W = -8e^{-4x}$.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & e^{-2x}\cos(x) & e^{-2x}\sin(x) \\
0 & 2e^{-2x}\sin(x) & -2e^{-2x}\cos(x) \\
0 & -4e^{-2x}\cos(x) & -4e^{-2x}\sin(x) \end{pmatrix} = 1\left(-8e^{-4x}\sin^2(x) - 8 e^{-4x}\cos^2(x) \right)=-8e^{-4x}$$
The answer in my booklet gives $-5e^{-4x}$, how did they get this?

Comment: The derivative of a product $uv$ is **not** $u'v'$.

Comment: I'd recommend denoting the unknown in the characteristic polynomial with literally any symbol other than $y$, e.g. $\lambda$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah yeah you're right! not sure how that passed me ..

Comment: @LutzLehmann I managed to get the solution in the end! $(e^{-2x}\cos(x))'(e^{-2x}\sin(x))''-(e^{-2x}\sin(x))'(e^{-2x}\cos(x))''$

Comment: Yes, that is the determinant formula. You could use that for those solutions $y''=-(4y'+5y)$ to reduce to $y_1'y_2''-y_1''y_2'=-5(y_1'y_2-y_1y_2')$. Next use that $y_1=uv$, $y_2=uw$ to get to $=-5u^2(v'w-vw')$, and so on.